# how to attach image in picture box in mail in c# windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I am trying to upload an image to a database and send an email when a user clicks a Save button. The database upload works when the user clicks save, but the email is not sending correctly.

Have I formatted `msg.body` correctly?

```
try
{
    u.Open();
    SqlCommand i = new SqlCommand("insert into BMS values('" + p + "')", u);
    i.ExecuteNonQuery();

    MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();

    Msg.From = new MailAddress("johnkumar3@gmail.com", "*****");
    Msg.To.Add("johnkumar05@gmail.com");

    string _fname = pictureBox1.ToString();

    Msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(_fname));
    Msg.Subject = "user credential sent from bank ";
    Msg.Body = "<img src=@'+ pictureBox.Image + />";                
    Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("johnkumar123@gmail.com", "****");
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.Send(Msg);

    MessageBox.Show("Data inserted successfully and data's mailed ");

    u.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
}
```

Comment: other than that doesnt seem like the way to send the actual image portion.. what happens when you try send it? which lines of code does it run? Id have expected you to get a mail with a single line of text saying Image or something in it

Comment: i think , code in msg.body is wrong - what code can be written therr ??

Comment: actually image is getting saved in DB but mail portion is not working , i like to send that image in form to mail id as attachment when save is clicked

Comment: I didnt say it wasnt going in the database, that doesnt look like a normal way to send an image  - you havent answered my questions though

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCv2j.jpg image of my form

Comment: I dont need to know what your form looks like

Comment: " that doesnt look like a normal way to send an image " yeah okay can u give me any code that will  attach image of the image in picture box to mail when save is clicked ?

Comment: i am not able to understand your question , can u ask me another time ?

Comment: Cleaned up language and formatted code

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show image in email body, you need upload image any website and put in email like that

```
Msg.Body = "<img src=" + pic_url + " />";
```

Try below code for send image  , also i suggest you add values with paramaters in sqlcommand

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("connection string");
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert into BMS values(@value1)", con);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", p);
        try
        {
            com.Connection.Open();
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
            Msg.From = new MailAddress("your email", "your display name");
            Msg.To.Add("to user name");
            string _fname = pictureBox1.ToString();

            Image image = pictureBox1.Image;

            System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            stream.Position = 0;

            Msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(stream, "Screenshot.jpg"));

            Msg.Subject = "user credential sent from bank ";


            Msg.Body = "content here ";
            Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "mail.cidcode.net";
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("your email", "your password");
            smtp.Send(Msg);

            MessageBox.Show("Data inserted successfully and data's mailed ");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test " + ex.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            com.Connection.Close();
            com.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this , i have a small  doubts in this code , in @value1 , what should i write ? ( com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", p); )

Comment: @value1 is any parametr , p is the value of parametr that you send to database

Comment: no error in code , it runs perfect but when i click save and proceed i am getting this  message " test transaction failed , the server response was sending addrss not accepted due to spam filter " help me to clear this error msg and send mail

Comment: You dont have to upload it to a website - you can attach it - and there are numerous examples of  how to do that. however your "spam filter" is your problem. Google have decided you are spamming them, you need to sort it out with them

Comment: probably  you try to send email with gmail account , i think that it is related gmail security. i tried my own email address , there is no problem .